# data from webform into database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, webforms

Hi guys I am new into PHP and need a little help solving my issue. I do apologize if this was already discussed. I do have a simple webform with two fields. Upon filling those fields user clicks submit button and data should be stored in the database. However I am not able to store it for reasons not known to me.

This is my index.php:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> INSERTING DATA TO DATABASE!!! </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/testbox.css" type="text/css"/>
<!-- Style sheet for form -->
</head>
<body>

<form action="../PHP/test.php" method="post">

    <div class="container">
    <p class="header">Title *</p>
        <input class="singleline" type="text" name="Title">
        <p class="footer">Meaningful, short descriptive title</p>
        <p class="header">Summary *</p>
        <textarea name="Summary"></textarea>
        <p class="footer">Brief summary of what the engagement involved.</p>
    <br>
    <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submit">
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is mytest.php:

```
<?php
$username = "root"; 
$password = "root";
$hostname = "127.0.0.1:80"; 
$dbname = "casestudy";

$dbcon = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (!dbcon) 
{
die ('error connecting to database');
}
echo 'you have connected successfully';

if(isset($_POST['submit']))  
{       
$Title= $_POST['Title']; 
$Summary= $_POST['Summary'];

    echo " this is a $Title and this is a $Summary !"; 

    $sql = "INSERT INTO example (title, summary) VALUES ('$Title', '$Summary')"; 

    $result = mysqli_query($sql);
        if ($result){
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('submitted successfully!')</script>";
            }
                else
            {
               echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('failed!')</script>";

            }
}
?>
```

My issues is the last step, when it tries to save it to database I get message "failed!" and I don't know where I have an errror. 
Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: BTW your query is ready to get injected

Comment: Use `mysqli_error($dbcon)` to see the error for failing to execute query.

Comment: I found the error, thanks for your help. Bub, this is just very simple example and it will not be used. I am going step by step and definitely will do my best to protected from injection. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass connection variable as [first](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) argument :

```
mysqli_query($dbcon, $sql);
```

Comment: I have passed connection into it however still same "failed" message.

Comment: I found the problem, $hostname = "127.0.0.1:80",. As soon as there is a port number specified it does not work for some reason. I have taken port number off and left only: 127.0.0.1 as a hostname and it saved without any problem.